# pyodbc executemany with tuple and python variable

Tags: python, python-2.7

My tuple looks like this:

```
test_tuple = ((1,2),(2,2),(3,5))
```

If I had a table with two columns, I can do:

```
executemany("insert into mytable (col1, col2) values (?, ?);", test_tuple)
```

Now if I wanted to insert into three columns, with the third column being a variable from Python, how can I achieve this?

```
ran_string_var = 'foo'

executemany("insert into mytable (col1, col2, col3) values (?, ?, ran_string_var);", test_tuple)
```

Results in table:

```
| col1 | col2 | col3 |
| 1    | 2    | foo  |
| 2    | 2    | foo  |
| 3    | 5    | foo  |
```

What are some of my options? Maybe add the variables I want into the tuple?

I cannot hard code the string with quotes because it will be dynamic.

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking - what your data really looks like what these 'extra variables' are, what the structure of the table you're inserting into is, your code doesn't look like actual code, etc. Take a look at [ask] and [mcve] and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: @pvg Sorry about that, I've updated it with slightly more information. Is that a little more clear?

Comment: Did you find the answer?